# Get argument name instead of value in a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to use the name of a vector instead of its value in a function.

```
a_vector <- 1:20
testFun <- function(x = a_vector) {
# Function should return "a_vector" and not 1:20
}
```

This is similar to what plot() is using by default for xlab where it uses the description of x.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `deparse/substitute`

```
testFun <- function(x = a_vector) {
       deparse(substitute(x))
   }

testFun()
#[1] "a_vector"
```